# How can I speed up page loading times with Brave browser and pi-hole?

Tags: macos, dns, brave, pihole

I notice that the combination of [Brave browser](https://brave.com/) and a [pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/) slowed down several pages such that I have to wait 20-30 seconds before the page is loaded and usable.

I tried the following to identify the issue:

- Used Safari and pi-hole DNS to visit the offending page: no slowdown
- Used Brave without pi-hole DNS (by setting the upstream DNS directly on my client) to visit the offending page: no slowdown
- Used Brave with "shields down" and with pi-hole DNS to visit the offending page: slow loading

So only when I combined Brave (with or without shields) with the pi-hole DNS I got the slowdown.

I tried the [suggested solution](https://pi-hole.net/2018/02/02/why-some-pages-load-slow-when-using-pi-hole-and-how-to-fix-it/#page-content) of setting up firewall rules on the raspberry, unfortunately this did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the FTLDNS blocking mode was the source of this issue.
By default it is set to [`NULL`](https://docs.pi-hole.net/ftldns/blockingmode/#pi-holes-unspecified-ip-blocking-default), returning the unspecified address `0.0.0.0` for blocked queries.

Apparently the Brave browser does not like it (for some pages?). Setting the blocking mode to [`NXDOMAIN`](https://docs.pi-hole.net/ftldns/blockingmode/#pi-holes-nxdomain-blocking) speeds up the loading time tremendously (from 20-30 seconds to maximum 1 second).